# Flask doesn't work Windows 7

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to run a minimal application from Flask quickstart. I installed Flask, set FLASK_APP and tried to: flask run

Here is app code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

and here is console answer:

```
E:\app>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "dapp.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python365\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "e:\python365\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Python365\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "e:\python365\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 890, in main
    cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
  etc...
  File "e:\python365\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 577, in __init
__
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "e:\python365\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "e:\python365\lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
  File "e:\python365\lib\socket.py", line 673, in getfqdn
    hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 0: invalid
start byte
```

What could make it?

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Is it possible that your hostname is an IDNA, containing non-ASCII characters? For example, if your host name is `me.českárepublika.icom.museum`, Windows _should_ be giving it to you as `xn--me.eskrepublika-ebb62d.icom.museum`, but if it it's instead giving you the Unicode string encoded as CP1250 (`b'\xe8esk\xe1republika.icom.museum'`), that could easily confuse Python.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.5. My hostname contains non-ASCII character. I've changed it. It works. Thanks.